# Problema Captcha Google

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

he implementado de la misma forma el Captcha de Google en varios formularios, en todos funciona correctamente menos en este, por algún motivo no envía la información del formulario. Gracias por la ayuda. Se envía solo la información referente al Captcha

```js
$('#login').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('6LfWd8AbAAAAAO1T9fOi4BT03QxPC-cNWYEYUVRh', {action: 'login'}).then(function(token) {
                $('#login').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="' + token + '">');
                $('#login').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">');
                $('#login').unbind('submit').submit();
            });
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="login" action="LoginCheck.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="row">
                        
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div style="padding-left:270px;">
                            <input type="text" name="usuario" class="form-date" placeholder="Usuario" data-validate = "Introduzca el Usuario" >
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div style="padding-left:270px;">
                                <span class="btn-show-pass">
                            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                        </span>
                            <input type="password" name="contraseña" class="form-date" placeholder="Contraseña" data-validate = "Introduzca la Contraseña" >
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div style="padding-left:20px;" >
                            <button value="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3"><span></span>Iniciar Sesión</button>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: no se supone que el captchat debe ejeutarce antes de entrar al submit???

Comment: No, esta opción es en segundo plano, no tienes que resolver el Captcha, a partir de la ip, cookies y comportamiento lo determina. Tienes alguna idea de porque no funciona? No envía la información del formulario, las dos variables del captcha sí, pero lo tengo implementado en otros formularios y funciona.

Comment: la verdad que no tengo indea por que no te funciona por que no he trabajado con ese capchat

Comment: pero me parece extraño que ejecutes el ready y el execution .... y luego con then ejecutes el submit; no se supone que el submit ocurre en el execution del capchat??